# Why my OPcache configuration in php.ini doesn't take effect?

Tags: opcache, php

I just configued OpCache in php.ini

```
zend_extension=opcache.so
opcache.memory_consumption=256
```

I am sure

```
zend_extension=opcache.so
```

took effect because when I comment it out, the opcache infomation no longer appears in phpinfo page.

but strange thing is,

```
opcache.memory_consumption=256
```

I found this parameter remains default value 64MB in phpinfo page:

[image: opcache configuration in phpinfo]

Could anyone tell me what did I miss ?

=====More Info===================

PHP version : 5.6.9
Server : nginx php-fpm
OS: CentOS

Comment: guess: restart php\apache

Comment: no luck :< I use nginx, and I tested it back and forth many times and restarted nginx and php-fpm everytime.

Comment: For a second there I thought you misspelled "Apache" xD